# Appium: Can we automate microsoft authentication login flow in mobile app if yes then how? If not then why?

Tags: mobile, appium, one-time-password

After entering the user email and password user get redirect to microsoft login page wherin he need to enter the otp received. Can we automate this flow in appium How?

Not getting anything

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Microsoft login page, but my guess is that you should be able to do it (as I was able to handle Facebook, Gmail/Google, Klarna, Paypal external WebView within a mobile app).
simply use Appium Inspector on their page which you are opening, look up for the necessary elements (they should be there) and work with them, just like you'd do with any other element

also what do you mean by "Not getting anything"?